# Spring boot - Multipart upload - 500 Internal server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipart

We were creating a upload call by using the spring boot multipart (Maven).

Our pom.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.awsarTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>awsarTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>awsarTest Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.21.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>CWSAuthentication</groupId>
            <artifactId>CWSAuthentication</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Authentication</groupId>
            <artifactId>Authentication</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>awsarTest</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

And springapplicationconfig.java`

```
package awsarTest.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "awsarTest.controller")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringApplicationConfig {

    
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vw = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vw.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");;
        vw.setSuffix(".jsp");;
        return vw;
    }
    
    
    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(5242880); // Set your max file size limit if needed
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Application.porperties files:

```
# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

And controller

```
package awsarTest.controller;

import com.opentext.livelink.service.core.Authentication;
import com.opentext.livelink.service.core.Authentication_Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthControllerTest {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public String authenticateUser(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username, @RequestParam(name = "password") String password ) {
        
        //return "Hello, " + name + "!";
        String USERNAME = username;
        String PASSWORD = password;

        // Create the Authentication service client
        Authentication_Service authService = new Authentication_Service();
        Authentication authClient = authService.getBasicHttpBindingAuthentication();

        // Store the authentication token
        String authToken;

        // Call the AuthenticateUser() method to get an authentication token
        try {
            System.out.print("Authenticating User...");
            authToken = authClient.authenticateUser(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("SUCCESS!\nAuthentication Token: " + authToken);
        } catch (SOAPFaultException e) {
            System.out.println("FAILED!\n");
            System.out.println(e.getFault().getFaultCode() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            return "Authentication failed";
        }

        // You can do further processing or return the token as needed
        return "Authentication Token: " + authToken;
    }
    
    **@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public String uplaoddocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        
        // Process the file (save it, perform operations, etc.)
           
        // For simplicity, this example just prints the file name
               
        String      fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();         System.out.println(
        "Received file: "
        + fileName);        
        // Return a response indicating success
        
        return fileName;
    }**
    
    
}
```

`if we run the upload call in the postman"http://localhost:6061/awsarTest/auth/upload":
we're getting error.

**"Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided"**

Answer (score 1):

In your uploaddocument method, the MultipartFile should be annotated with @RequestPart, not @RequestParam (although it's not a problem if you leave it as @RequestParam)

```
    public String uplaoddocument(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

Another thing to check would be in your DispatcherServletInitilizer class (or web.xml).  You must provide additional configuration to allow the Dispatcher Servlet to handle MultipartFiles

```
/**
 * Additional configuration for the Dispatcher Servlet
 * @param registration
 */
@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    // Set Multipart support to temporarily store uploaded files in the below path
    // Saves uploaded files under /your/upload/location, sets the max file size to 5242880B, the max size of the multipart request to <maxRequestSize>,
    // and max file size that can be uploaded without being written to disk (<FileSizeThreshold> bytes)
    registration.setMultipartConfig( new MultipartConfigElement("/your/upload/location", 5242880, <maxRequestSize>, <FileSizeThreshold>) );
}
```